# Prove that $\forall n \geq N$, $|a_n|>\frac{|a|}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

Given that $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is a convergent sequence such that $a_n \to a \ne 0$, then prove that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$  such that $\forall n \geq N$, $|a_n|>\frac{|a|}{2}$

We have $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$

$$|a_n-a|<\epsilon$$
$\implies$
$$a-\epsilon <a_n <a-\epsilon \to (1)$$

Now on the contrary, let there is no naturl number $N$ such that $|a_n|>\frac{|a|}{2}$. That means $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$|a_n| \leq \frac{|a|}{2}$$
$\implies$
$$-\frac{|a|}{2} \leq a_n \leq \frac{|a|}{2} \to (2)$$

I am stuck here

Comment: Once you have deduced (2), you are done because you have found infinitely many indices $n$ such that $a_n\in [-|a|/2, |a|/2]$. This contradicts convergence because $a_n\in B_{|a|/2}(a)$ for all $n$ large, but $B_{|a|/2}(a)\cap [-|a|/2, |a|/2] = \emptyset$!

Comment: This is not necessarily true if $a=0$. (Take $a_n = 0$ for all $n$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick $\epsilon = |a|/2$ and use the triangle inequality: $|a|\le |a_n-a| + |a_n|$.

---

Added: Suppose for the sake of contradiction that for infinitely many $n$, we had $|a_n|\le |a|/2$. Then $|a_n-a|\ge |a|-|a_n|\ge |a|/2$ for these $n$. (Notice we used the same inequality in the direct proof.) This contradicts convergence.

Comment: Can't i proceed with the way i started?

Comment: @Umeshshankar: Sure thing. I think that a direct proof is psychologically easier, but a proof by contradiction is certainly a viable way to go. I added the details in my answer. It is good to get out of the habit of replacing absolute value inequalities with two inequalities involving positive and negative signs since it is often unnecessary, and the statements hold in the more general context of metric spaces, where there is no notion of "sign." It is more versatile and simpler to think in terms of distances and to have a picture in mind.